# Mi background no se muestra al subir proyecto en IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis, background

tengo un proyecto hecho en asp mvc, pues tiene un background que funciona mientras lo uso en localhost la imagen esta guardada dentro del proyecto, pero cuando publico el proyecto en IIS no se me muestra el background.

Codigo css

```
body {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        margin: auto;
        background-image: url('../../template/imagenes/fondoazul.jpg');
    }
```

Comment: Click derecho... Inspeccionar elemento... Modificar la ruta "on the fly" (en ese editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reemplaza:

```
background-image: url('../../template/imagenes/fondoazul.jpg');
```

Por:

```
background-image: url('~/CSS/template/imagenes/fondoazul.jpg');
```

Donde CSS es la carpeta que está en raíz, el signo `~` hace que vayas a la raíz del proyecto